# Документация swift языка

Tags: swift

Есть у меня определенные трудности при работе с документацией Apple по языку Swift, не пойму как ею пользоваться.

Смотрите: изучаю метки на карте, у меня получается создается объект класса  MKPointAnnotation.

```
    // пишу координаты точки, где нужно создать заколку

    let firstLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.073992, 14.450272)
    // Создаем заколку
    let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    dropPin.coordinate = firstLoc
    dropPin.title = "Здесь хорошее место"
    dropPin.subtitle = "А это подзаголовок"
    mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
```

Я хочу посмотреть описание класса MKPointAnnotation, например, я не знал, что можно прописать dropPin.subtitle, я писал dropPin.description и это вызывало ошибку.

То есть я хочу видеть все методы и все ... члены класса, ну в общем, все что я могу менять или что мне нужно обязательно переписать override. Для этого, я обычно смотрю документацию. Здесь же я жму документацию на MKPointAnnontation и вижу только какую-то шляпу, что там можно задать coordinate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Больше я там ничего не вижу, в итоге мне приходится вместо того, чтобы просто смотреть в документацию, искать кучу мануалов и туториалов, что очень сильно тормозит понимание. А как это вообще у вас происходит? Перед изучением языка я читал, что у Apple очень крутая документация, у меня есть подозрение, что смотреть нужно где-то в другом месте. Где смотреть то, что мне нужно?

Comment: а где документацию смотрите?

Comment: Когда в xCode ставлю курсор на класс, справа появляется по нему справка и там есть Reference на класс, вот ее жму, октрывается справка по языку сразу на страницу класса. Есть там еще ссылка на гайды, но это учебник по сути, там 20 страниц и сходу не нашел даже мой класс. Вот тут тоже самое: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPointAnnotation_class/

Comment: Я поднялся вверх по иерархии классов на NSShape и увидел там title и subtitle, но это немножко не очевидно, т.к. если взять за правило, что можно подниматься, то дальше идет NSObject, разве с ним тоже можно работать через MKPointAnnotation? Плаваю в этом немного

Comment: я бы все таки не стал обвинять эпл в вашем незнании, что такое наследование. mkpointannotation унаследован от mkshape (это есть в документации сверху) и добавляет к нему только координату. а уже mkshape имеет title и так далее.

Comment: Я знаю, что такое наследование, смотрите ответ выше, однако это не решает проблему, опять таки, смотрите выше и Apple я не обвиняю, пока только интересуюсь, пока.

Comment: так в чем вопрос тогда? эпл в описании класса дает только переменные и методы этого класса, а не всей цепочки наследования - это нормально. представьте какая каша бы была, если бы в каждом документе были все методы nsobject

Comment: Вопрос в том, что это неудобно и есть ли способы получше? Это вопрос не к вам, вашу позицию я понял. У меня бы не было каши из-за того, что в описание класса сразу бы добавили все возможные данные, которые можно дергать, а не бегать искать их "по этажам". Так же было бы неплохо написать рядом подобные классы по работе с point annotation, в общем сделать для людей. Сейчас у меня подобная проблема с MKPointAnnotation, в мануале есть только координаты, заголовок и подзаголовок, однако если пройти в меню через conforms to MKAnnotation, то можно увидеть кучу всего другого - это и есть неочевидность

Comment: Я не хочу сказать, что это не очевидно для всех, я хочу сказать, что это не очевидно для новых юзеров, как минимум, которым этот мануал ой как нужен.

Answer (score 2):

Ну хотя "вопрос и не ко мне", попробую ответить.

Документация, которую вы приводите, является просто референсом касательно того, какие переменные/функции существуют в данном конкретном классе, и дает ссылки на все классы/протоколы которые каким то образом связанны с ним.

То, что вам надо, это документация по MapKit и как им пользоваться.

[Maps For Developers](https://developer.apple.com/maps/)

[Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Annotating Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1)